# What's the proper name for the 'Food Bars'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Just in case you dont know what i'm referring to it's these:
[image]

I've heard them called Shanks, Food Bars, and Health Bars. I'm wondering what the proper (official) name for these is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There are multiple names.

Here are some of the names referenced on the Minecraft Wiki. First, is "Hunger Indicator".

> The hunger indicator is shown above hot bar, to the other side from health indicator.
> <sub><sup>*- [Hunger - Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger)*</sup></sub>

To me this name seems the most fitting, seeing as it matches the "Health Inidcator".

Next, we get two in one: the hunger bar / food bar.

> The player's hunger value is shown on the heads-up display in the form of a hunger bar (also called food bar)
> <sub><sup>*- [Hunger - Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger)*</sup></sub>

After reading this, I realised that the "Health Bar" has multiple names, so any of these names listed above are acceptable.

<sub>Note: there are probably several other names for this, these are all the ones that i found</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It's either *hunger value* or *food bar*. I've taken this from [jeb directly](https://twitter.com/jeb_/status/111047534318858240) and the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger).

Answer (score -1):

One name for the "Food bar", is the Hunger bar

> The player's hunger value is shown on the heads-up display in the form of a hunger bar (also called food bar), which is similar to health bar (located above the hotbar), located opposite to it and represented by ten drumsticks.

-https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger

It is also more commonly referred to as the Food bar, but it can also be referred to as the Hunger meter

> Saturation is the first statistic to decrease when a player performs energy-intensive actions, and it must be completely depleted before the visible hunger meter begins decreasing.

-https://minecraft.wiki/w/Food#Hunger_and_Saturation

Also referred to as the Hunger Indicator, it is referred to differently in different contexts, although the most common is the Food Bar